# Identifying a connection ID in Postgres

Tags: delphi, postgresql, database-connection

I have a Postgres database (9) that I am writing a trigger for.  I want the trigger to set the modification time, and user id for a record.  In Firebird you have a CONNECTIONID that you can use in a trigger, so you could add a value to a table when you connect to the database (this is a desktop application, so connections are persistent for the lifetime of the app), something like this:

```
UserId | ConnectionId
---------------------
544    | 3775
```

and then look up in the trigger that connectionid 3775 belongs to userid 544 and use 544 as the user that modified the record.

Is there anything similar I can use in Postgres?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you could use the process id. It can be retrieved with:

```
pg_backend_pid()
```

With this pid you can also use the table pg_stat_activity to get more information about the current backend, althouht you already should know everything, since you are using this backend.

Or better. Just create a serial, and retrieve one value from it for each connection:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE 'connectionids';
```

And then:

```
SELECT next_val('connectionids');
```

in each connection, to retrieve a connection unique id.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I checked this out, and this changes during the lifetime of the connection to the database.  I need something that doesn't change.

Comment: This does not change! If it does, you don't really use the same connection. Check, if you have a connection pool, and are accidentially retrieving connection from it!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I use EMS Studio for Postgres, and I checked this out there, and each time I opened a new query window I got a new result.  I made the assumption that it changed per transaction or so.  Perhaps EMS opens a new connection for every query window?  I will build a test app with a connection I control, and check it out there and let you know if it works.

Comment: Your sequence idea wont work, I need something like the pid I can read per connection.  I can create a sequence, but how do I associate that in the trigger.  Hopefully the PID deal works, I will let you know asap.

Comment: pg_backend_pid() (not sure where `pg_get_pid()` comes from?) certainly does identify a connection. Using one connection per query window sounds very plausible- mssql enterprise manager, toad etc work that way (by default)

Comment: Daniel, while your create sequence wont work with the given scenario, after testing pg_backend_pid() I can see it is not changed during the connection lifetime, and I had made an incorrect assumption based on the software I was testing it with.  Using pg_backend_pid() in the way I described in my post is what I am after.  Thanks to you and araqnid.

Comment: Sorry, it was pg_backend_pid(), don't know where I read pg_get_pid().

Comment: If your client program is opening a new connection each time you run a query...  You'll get a new pid each time.  Build a script and run it as a one transaction / session file, with psql -1 -f filename.sql dbnamehere and see what it does.

Answer (score 6):

One way is to use the `custom_variable_classes` configuration option.  It appears to be designed to allow the configuration of add-on modules, but can also be used to store arbitrary values in the current database session.

Something along the lines of the following needs to be added to `postgresql.conf`:

```
custom_variable_classes = 'local'
```

When you first connect to the database you can store whatever information you require in the custom class, like so:

```
SET local.userid = 'foobar';
```

And later in on you can retrieve this value with the `current_setting()` function:

```
SELECT current_setting('local.userid');
```

Adding an entry to a log table might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO audit_log VALUES (now(), current_setting('local.userid'), ...)
```

Comment: custom_variable_classes is no longer needed. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29964

Answer (score 4):

While it may work for your desktop use case, note that process ID numbers do rollover (32768 is a common upper limit), so using them as a unique key to identify a user can run into problems.  If you ever end up with leftover data from a previous session in the table that's tracking user->process mapping, that can collide with newer connections assigned the same process id once it's rolled over.  It may be sufficient for your app to just make sure you aggressively clean out old mapping entries, perhaps at startup time given how you've described its operation.

To avoid this problem in general, you need to make a connection key that includes an additional bit of information, such as when the session started:

```
SELECT procpid,backend_start FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE procpid=pg_backend_pid();
```

That has to iterate over all of the connections active at the time to compute, so it does add a bit of overhead.  It's possible to execute that a bit more efficiently starting in PostgreSQL 8.4:

```
SELECT procpid,backend_start FROM pg_stat_get_activity(pg_backend_pid());
```

But that only really matters if you have a large number of connections active at once.

Comment: It's called "pid" (not "procpid") in 9.5, I forgot exactly when was the column renamed, maybe in 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`current_user`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) if you need the database user (I'm not sure that's what you want by reading your question).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I use the same user for all the connections, and have an internally defined user table in the database, so that won't work.